# How can we make connecting to openvpn access server not prompt password?

Tags: networking, server, systemd, openvpn

My Ubuntu 20.04 connect to remote openvpn access server using systemd unit.

```
ubuntu@worker-0-node1:~$ sudo systemctl start openvpn@client
 Enter Auth Username: ovpnserve
 Enter Auth Password: ***********
```

How can I disable this prompt so that password gets filled in without prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconfigure your OpenVPN unit and file that it refers to for the configuration to provide a username/password file.

From [this post on the OpenVPN.net forums](https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?t=11342), add this to your **OpenVPN configuration file** (NOT the SystemD unit!) that 'client' uses:

```
auth-user-pass login.conf
```

and then configure the login.conf file to have the username and password in this format:

```
username
password
```

Make sure that you use the full path to the file for `login.conf` if it's not in the OpenVPN directory, and whatever user that OpenVPN unit calls can access it.

Comment: tried didnt worked, the openvpn@client is runing as root user and the creds file is in `/etc/openvpn`  to `ExecStart` I passed `--auth-user-pass login.conf` beside other existing  args.

Comment: to be precise `auth-user-pass pass.txt` needs to be added to profile configuration file not systemd unit. and it worked.

Comment: Apologies I wasn't cleaer enough in my answer, I've revised that.  Glad to see it's working :)